InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException after Google Sign-In in React Native with AWS Amplify
I am developing a React Native app using Expo and AWS Amplify for authentication. I have configured Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool for Google authentication. However, after signing in with Google on Safari and being redirected back to the app, I encounter the following error:
LOG  Sign in failure [InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.]

Here is the relevant part of my code:
useEffect(() => {
    Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      console.log('hi')
      switch (event) {
        case 'signIn':
          // Successful sign-in handling
          console.log('User signed in');
          break;
        case 'signOut':
          // Successful sign-out handling
          console.log('User signed out');
          break;
        case 'signIn_failure':
          // Sign-in failure handling
          console.log('Sign in failure', data);
          break;
      }
    });
  }, []);

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
   Auth.federatedSignIn({
     provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google,
})}>

I have ensured that the Cognito User Pool is correctly configured for Google authentication. However, I am not sure why the Identity Pool is involved here and why this error is occurring.
Any insights or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the complete solution with the additional information about the role and updating the IAM trust policy:
I found a way to solve my issue regarding the InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool. error.
The solution was to look up the authRole that amplify-cli creates and add trust relationships. The role is something like this: amplify-app-dev-00000-authRole. Here is the edited trust policy in the IAM trust relationships section:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-west-2:<COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID>"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

You need to update the trust policy in the IAM trust relationships section of the role.
